# Complex query in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

I'm trying to build a simple solver web application for the [VRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem). My question is on how can i build a query that returns every customer with his user's username, longitude, latitude and his products with all product columns **and** the quantity of product's last stock?

The diagram of the database:
[image: database scheme]
Customer and User relationship is one-to-one (User is a superclass of Customer)

Salesman and User relationship is one-to-one (User is a superclass of Salesman)

Salesman and Customer relationship is one-to-many (a Salesman has many Customers)

Customer and Product relationship is one-to-many (a Customer has many Products)

Product and Stock relationship is one-to-many (there is a need of recording every stock change)

*Any suggestion of changing the database scheme is welcome*

Comment: Can you post your the relationship of your models, specifically User, Customer, Product and Stock. Also how is Customer different from User (can you explain in a business sense how they differ)?

Comment: @the12 we assume that the latest stock of a product is the current stock the the salesman have to deliver to the customer. Please also see the edits for the relationships

Comment: If "most recent stock level" is a frequently required value, then I'd consider dedicating a table to it, or updating the product table with its value. It could be the difference between a ten second query and a one second query. Depending on data volumes etc. of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is structured in such a complicated way, having everything retrieved with ActiveRecord objects will become very slow very fast (recently had this problem).

Let's see what we can figure out together.

Since you did not provide sample data for the MySQL question, I filled it in myself, but feel free to improve the data and we might come to a better solution.

#### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   `latitude` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `customer_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stocks` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(200) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `longitude`, `latitude`) VALUES
  (1, 'username1', '11.12', '22.33'),
  (2, 'username2', '11.12', '22.33'),
  (3, 'username3', '11.12', '22.33');
INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `user_id`) VALUES
  (9, 1),
  (10, 2),
  (11, 3);
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `customer_id`) VALUES
  (33, 9),
  (34, 10),
  (35, 11);
INSERT INTO `stocks` (`id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, `updated_at`) VALUES
  (1, 33, 12, '2017-07-17 13:24:01'),
  (2, 34, 1, '2017-07-17 13:24:02'),
  (3, 35, 99, '2017-07-17 13:24:03'),
  (4, 36, 3, '2017-07-17 13:31:01');
```

#### Query

```
SELECT users.id, username, longitude, latitude, products.id as product_id, quantity from `users`
INNER JOIN customers ON user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN products ON customer_id = customers.id
INNER JOIN stocks ON product_id = products.id
ORDER BY stocks.updated_at DESC
```

#### Results

```
id  username    longitude   latitude    product_id  quantity
1   username1   11.12       22.33       33          12
2   username2   11.12       22.33       34          1
3   username3   11.12       22.33       35          99
```

For the Rails part you can use something like:

```
data = Users.select("id, longitude etc").
  joins(
    "INNER JOIN customers ON user_id = users.id etc "
)
```

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a453cf/3)

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to build a query for each and every one of the models.

You could start off by building a single query for customers: `@customers = Customer.all` and from there via the relationships that exist between the different models, can access whatever data you want.

i.e.:

Querying the customer's username, longitude, and latittude (Used the first customer as an example, but you can query using `Customer.where(:user_id => some_number)` or using `.find`.

```
customer = Customer.all.first
customer.user.username
customer.user.longtitude
customer.user.latitude
```

The query below would work for grabbing the first customer's first product, and the first stock for that product. Once again you can use different methods such as `.find` and `.where` to query the exact product and resulting stock you need.

```
customer.products.first.stocks.first
```

If you wanted to grab all customers (using an instance variable for `@customers = Customer.all` and loop through each one and output a result, it would look something like this:

```
@customers.each do |customer|
 customer.username
end
```

Comment: Yes, but if you want to sort the customers by the sum of their products quantities wouldn't be so simple/efficient even for 30 customers with 80 products each. That's why i'd like a "sql-oriented" solution rather than "feth everything and manipulate the arrays of objects"

Comment: IMO, they are two separate things. One is how you should grab all the models/attributes that you need. That can be done using the ActiveRecord associations that I showed. The other is how you should specifically sort those results with a complex query such as "sort the customers by the sum of their product quantities". For that query, you should have a column for the amount of products in the database for the model Customer. Everytime a quantity gets changed for a product, it should update that column. You could just then query that using `Customer.all.order(:total_quantity => :asc)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the method inside the model class and with relevant relationships returns everything you need. Take a glance in rails documentation active record